# How to inherit the commonName to the subject alternative name

Tags: openssl

On my pc with Windows 10 installed, I have to use OpenSSL.
I have downloaded the version 1.0.2n and following this guide: [Creating an SSL Certificate with Multiple Hostnames](http://apetec.com/support/GenerateSAN-CSR.htm) I modified the openssl.cfg configuration file (located in C:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin).

After some testing, I can generate with no problem both keys and certificates.

My problem is the following: my indications for the certificates generation are such that the **Subject Alternative Name** must have only 1 value and must match with the **Common Name** field.
So, if (filling out certificate) I fill the commonName field with **example.com**, also the Subject Alternative Name must be **example.com**.
I know that I can change every time the cfg file and set manually the value for the SAN in the v3-req section, but I want avoid this; I'm searching for a way to copy the value I prompt for the common name in the SAN field.

So, I tried this: in the openss.cfg file I went to v3 req section and I changed it in this way:

```
[ v3_req ]

# Extensions to add to a certificate request

basicConstraints = CA:FALSE 
keyUsage = nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment 
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[alt_names] 
DNS.1 = commonName:copy
```

that is, I tried to exploit the :copy function but, unfortunately, this action does not work. If, after certificate generation, I launch the command

```
req -text -noout -in <filename.csr>
```

to verify my certificate, in the specific section I get this:

```
X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:
    DNS:commonName.copy
```

As you can see, the output is the right side of my declaration under the `[alt_names]` section.

So, the questions are: Is there a method to to inherit the commonName to the subject alternative name? And if yes, how?

Comment: From the documentation, `:copy` applies only to `issuer` or `email`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `${section::name}` to read previously defined variables.

Here's an example that works:

```
[ req ]

prompt             = no
string_mask        = default

# The size of the keys in bits:
default_bits       = 2048
distinguished_name = req_dn
req_extensions     = req_ext

[ req_dn ]

# Or traditional org style:
countryName = gb
organizationName = example
commonName = acme.example.test

[ req_ext ]

subjectAltName = @alt_names

[alt_names]
DNS.1 = ${req_dn::commonName}
DNS.2 = alt.example.test
```

Followed by:

```
openssl req -nodes -new -keyout test.key -out test.csr -config ./openssl.cnf
```

This results in:

```
openssl req -noout -text -in test.csr
```

giving:

```
 ...
    Attributes:
    Requested Extensions:
        X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:
            DNS:acme.example.test, DNS:alt.example.test
Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
     92:1c:e0:0e:6d:7d:2e:b4:64:c5:ab:ff:6a:37:dd:35:98:58:
 ...
```

Comment: Thanks, it works!
Can I ask you another question?
This option works if I want to inherit the default value with which I set the commonName variable in the cfg file.
If I wanted to compile everything dynamically, how could I do it? That is, when I run the command to generate the certificate (req -new -out <file_name> .csr -key <file_name> .key) I am queried about the values I want to use for the variables: Country name, State, Locality, etc. Among these variables, I was asked to set the Common Name; if I wanted this value to be used for SAN, is there a way?

Comment: It works there too.  Personally, I wouldn't use that method as you're leaving yourself open to smelling pisstakes when you enter the details.  Create a config similar to the above and copy to each scenario/server in turn.  Edit once, check it, then you can re-use when it's time to renew a certificate.  Much safer.

Comment: I just tried this, in my [ req_dn ], I have commonName = supplied (it's in the CSR). And in the [alt_names], I added ${req_dn::commonName}... and in my resulting certificate, I'm getting "supplied" in subject alt name. So basically, it doesn't work as I expected.

Comment: @pHeoz - The above creates the CSR, so I'm not sure what you mean by _it's in the CSR_.  If you define the `commonName` variable as `supplied` then it's no surprise that the value of that variable is applied to the SAN.